SVG rounds edges with large stroke-width
I met a problem during sankey diagram generating with d3 and screenshoting it with html2canvas.

D3 looks fine with this code of links:



<svg id="svg" width="740" height="400">
  <g fill="none" cursor="crosshair">
    <g>
      <path d="M257.33333333333337,206.57434256574345C314.1666666666667,206.57434256574345,314.1666666666667,206.57434256574345,335,206.57434256574345" stroke="#FFC700" stroke-width="259.8035196480352" stroke-alignment="outer"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M334,206.57434256574345C390.83333333333337,206.57434256574345,390.83333333333337,206.57434256574345,446.6666666666667,206.57434256574345" stroke="#FFC700" stroke-width="259.8035196480352" stroke-alignment="outer"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M445.6666666666667,206.57434256574345C502.5,206.57434256574345,502.5,206.57434256574345,558.3333333333334,206.57434256574345" stroke="#FFC700" stroke-width="259.8035196480352" stroke-alignment="outer"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
      <path d="M557.3333333333334,206.57434256574345C614.1666666666667,206.57434256574345,614.1666666666667,205.77014528985393,705,205.77014528985393" stroke="#FFC700" stroke-width="259.8035196480352" stroke-alignment="outer"></path>
    </g>
  </g>0
</svg>




but during screenshotting it became this:


I googled / researched everything I could, got that the problem in stroke-width of SVG. Once it too big edges are rounding. How to solve this issue?
PS most of people are recommend stroke-linecap="butt" it doesn't work there...

So, the problem isn't SVG per se, but how html2canvas might be changing content that it's converting to canvas? Wouldn't the problem be in the guts of html2canvas somewhere?

Probably not causing this issue but stroke-alignment="outer" isn't supported by any browser – and won't have any effect even if it was supported. Besides, there is a minor syntax error: you have a zero before the closing SVG end tag.

yeah, for sure I don't use stroke-alignment="outer" - it was just an experiment
